# Verifying the format of a text file?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have an application that downloads a `.txt` file via FTP, and then it calls some sql to insert the file data into my database. I want to check whether the file is in the correct format before trying to insert.

The file should consist of some number of rows, each with the following format:

`(4 letter code) (tab) (3 or 4 letter code) (tab) (date as dd-MMM-yy) (tab) (variable length text description) (tab) (1 letter code)`

Is there a good way to check whether every line in the file follows this pattern, and warn me if it doesn't?

Comment: I took the liberty and added the 'regex' tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a typical use case for [regular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression_examples).
Create a regex pattern and match it against each line in your file.

If you aren't familiar with regex, maybe you'll find [this link](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html) also helpfull in addition to the links above.

The pattern you are looking for is propably this:

```
    ^\w{4}\t\w{3,4}\t\d{2}\-\D{3}\-\d{2}\t.*\t\w$
```

it will match text like these (imagine _ is a tab):

```
test_foo_12-FEB-11_this is a text_X
test_fbar_01-jan-15_bla bka bla_o
```

but not:

```
test123_foo_12-FEB-11_this is a text
```

You could do something like this:

```
Dim pattern = "^\w{4}\t\w{3,4}\t\d{2}\-\D{3}\-\d{2}\t.*\t\w$"
For Each line In text
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}", _
                      line, _
                      If(Regex.IsMatch(line, pattern), "is valid", "is invalid"))
Next
```

Comment: You could go further and check that the date portion is actually a valid date.

Comment: That exercise is left to the questioner :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, it works a charm. Is checking validity of dates something you can do with regex, then?

Comment: Basically yes, but it is not worth the effort imho. If you really need to check the validity of a date string, i would rather use something like DateTime.TyrParse()